# Create a checklist in Excel where I can check off with the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

How can I create a checklist in Excel where I can check off with the keyboard?

I have found tutorials like this http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/checklist.html but I only want to use the keyboard when I work with the checklist and not the mouse when I tick the boxes.

Of course I can have an empty cell that I'm ticking off with an x but thought if there are any nicer ways?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, your cursor focus will always be a cell, you can't specify a focus range as the set of check boxes. The alternative solution is to use a data entry form, for which there is a guide here https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Simplify-data-entry-with-a-data-form-00bfc75e-f675-46ad-8703-291fc03e4d77